# How do we install additional fonts for xepersian on MiKTeX 2.9 Win XP/Win 7

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I want to install  several fonts such as
IranNastaliq
Niloofar
and several others.
How is this done?

Comment: Did you try the usual Windows font installation procedure?

Comment: Seems to me not related to LaTeX. Possibly off topic?

Comment: This is clearly related to TeX, the subject tells it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply install them in Windows Fonts directory, and then [`XePersian`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian) can access them through `\defpersianfont` and etc.
to do this:

- Open "Control Panel",
- Choose "Fonts" (perhaps under Appearance and Personalization),
- File>Install New Font...

an alternative solution is to use `ExternalLocation` option, which search for the font in local directory and search paths.

However, installing the font is recommended.

You can also find several persian fonts (including those you mention) in [www.parsilatex.com](http://www.parsilatex.com)

Comment: In Windows 7 one can simply right click the .ttf/.otf files and choose Install.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Vihrov and Zakeri. Yes installation to Windows font directory was enough. I was under the impression that they have to go to a special TDS location. I got the fonts from http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=82&func=select&id=5